# What are free services available for creating MySQL on cloud?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, mysql, database, free

I am new to web development. My team is planning to create a dynamic website as a project. I want to have a relational database ( MySQL) but all tutorials seem to use MySQL and PHP locally. We want to create a website we could host ( on a free service like heroku). Please tell me how can I use MySQL on cloud freely( we do not want to use our computer as server). Any alternate solution is also welcome.

Comment: This is absolutely inappropriate here.  That said, mysql can be run on almost any VPS, so find yourself a free VPS, install and configure MySQL and you have an answer.

Comment: Heroku supports both mysql and php.